# Language with separate get/set publicity

Tags: programming-languages

I've been writing a personal project, and keep coming across cases where a field needs to be publicly readable, but shouldn't be publicly writable. As far as I know, the accepted "good practice" in these cases is to make the field private, write a vanilla getter, and let that be all.

It seems that you could save the overhead of the getter (both in terms of execution and developer time) by allowing the programmer to set separate levels of publicity for read/write access, much like UNIX file permissions.

Are there any languages where this is possible?

Comment: What is the model of users in your project? What does 'public' means?

Comment: There are no users.
I'm talking about class field publicity (public, private, protected).

Comment: Ruby inverts this: there is no public access to instance variables, period. Both read and write always require an accessor (in Ruby parlance). You can autogenerate a default accessor (variable read/write) very easily; the autogenerated accessors are optimised for speed. Thus, `attr_reader :foo` will do what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences between the UNIX file system permission and a class' instance variables visibility (public, protected, private, global etc.). The former is an [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) which defines a list of permissions attached to an object, and the latter [defines how much the rest of the system can access the variable](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4b.html).

Anyway, with that out of the way...

Ruby deals with this by defining:

- [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)
- [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader)
- [`attr_writer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer)

So if I have a `Blog` class that looks like:

```
class Blog
  attr_accessor :title
end
```

The `attr_accessor :title` is translated into a 'getter' and a 'setter' like this:

```
def title=(value)
  @title = value
end

def title
  @title
end
```

Conversely, if I defined `attr_reader :title` in the same class, it gets translated into a 'getter':

```
def title
  @title
end
```

while `attr_writer :title` gets translated into a 'setter':

```
def title=(value)
  @title = value
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
On UNIX: sure, so they're really only similar when you're talking about modifying the global access permissions.

Comment: @Shriken Yes, I understand why you used that comparison. Just thought I will share a bit of the underlying details after reading Fumu's comment.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can use an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```cs
public int Foo { get; private set; }
```

This saves most of the complexity of writing a separate getter method. And the execution time overhead of such getter should be none (thanks to inlining) or very small.